# ¿Como instalo doctrine/dbal en laravel 5.3?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel

Intento instalarlo editando mi archivo `composer.json` de la siguiente manera:

```
"require": {
    "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
    "doctrine/dbal": "v2.4.5"
},
```

Y luego ejecutando el comando `composer update`.

Pero esto me lanza el siguiente error:
[image]

La versión que utilizo la extraigo de acá:
[doctrine/dbal](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal.html)

Comment: Eso parece ser un problema de composer. Mira esta pregunta: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635257/composer-content-length-mismatch

Comment: Probastes ejecutar este comando: `composer require doctrine/dbal` ?

Comment: @amenadiel voy a probar lo que dice en esa pregunta

Comment: @Jemonge si hermano

Comment: @amenadiel formaliza la pregunta para darte la aprobación, efectivamente esa pregunta resolvió mi problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finalmente, la respuesta estaba en una *aparente* corrupción de la instalación de composer,o bien una configuración faltante. La solución está  descrita en StackOverflow: [composer-content-length-mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38635257/composer-content-length-mismatch) e incluye los siguientes pasos:

Listar la configuración de composer con

```
composer config --list --global
```

Esto mostrará entre otros settings el directorio que composer considera como `[home]`. Por ejemplo

```
[home] /home/{username}/.composer
```

Dentro de ese directorio, hay que editar el archivo `config.json` para forzar el uso de https al conectarse a packagist

```
{
    "config": {
    "github-protocols": [
      "https"
    ]
  },
  "repositories": {
    "packagist": {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://packagist.org"
    }
  }
}
```

La respuesta sugiere también añadir una entrada a la sección `repositories` del archivo `composer.json` de tu proyecto. En este caso, **añade packagist explícitamente como un repositorio**. Se adjunta un ejemplo de cómo quedaría el `composer.json` de laravel:

```
{
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "laravel/framework": "5.2.*"
  },
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
  },
  "repositories": {
    "packagist": {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://packagist.org"
    }
  }
}
```

Repito, sólo estoy replicando lo que figura en la respuesta de S.O. que enlacé en mi comentario.

Comment: gracias hermano